# how do i break this python loop in a efficent manner after ive entered a valid number

Tags: python, loops, break, code-cleanup

```
while True:
    month_num = int(input("enter the month number: "))
    if month_num == 1:
        print("january")
    elif month_num == 2:
      print("February")
    elif month_num == 3:
      print("March")
    elif month_num == 4:
      print("April")
    elif month_num == 5:
      print("May")
    elif month_num == 6:
      print("June")
    elif month_num == 7:
      print ("July")
    elif month_num == 8:
      print ("August")
    elif month_num == 9:
      print ("September")
    elif month_num == 10:
      print ("October")
    elif month_num == 11:
      print ("November")
    elif month_num == 12:
      print ("December")
    else:
      print("Enter a valid number")
```

i want to end the code cleanly but dont know to go about doind it i just stared it but i want to do it so that if i do put in the vlaues from 1 to 12 it would break after but i dont know how to do it efficently

Comment: How about `if month_num == 0:` / `break`?

Comment: You might consider putting the months in a list, so you can do `if 1 <= month_num <= 12:` / `print(month_name[month_num-1])`.

Comment: For this code you could have before the loop: `month_num = 0`. Then change the condition to `while month_num < 1 or month_num > 12:`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import calendar

while True:
  try:
    month_num = int(input("enter the month number: "))
    if 0 < month_num < 13:
      print(calendar.month_name[month_num])
      break
  except ValueError:
    pass
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.